# Chemfig – Charges in skeletal formulas

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I’m trying to write a reaction mechanism but there’s a problem. If I want to add charges to ”invisible“ C atoms, the skeletal formula gets broken (see right molecule).

[image]

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\def\CF@node@content{%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
\ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=los,name=Schema,within=section,placement=htbp]{scheme}

\renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\sffamily\cf{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
\begin{center}
  \chemfig{-[:30](=[::+60]O)-[:-30]-[:30]\chembelow{}{$\scriptstyle\oplus$}(-[:90])-[:-30]N(-[:-90]H)-[:30]OH}
\end{center}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

I hope there’s an option without showing the carbon atoms. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use invisible bond:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{-[:30](=[::+60]O)-[:-30]-[:30](-[:-90,0.2,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\oplus)(-[:90])-[:-30]N(-[:-90]H)-[:30]OH}
\end{document}
```

[image]