# Chemical bonds and atom position with chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have been working in the cylindrospermopsin structure using `chemfig`. The structure is:[image]

I draw it with te following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{standalone} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Para copiar caracteres especiais como ç, á, à
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Para copiar caracteres especiais como ç, á, à
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{%
*6(-(-[:-72]?[a])(<[:-150]H)-N*6(-^{+}(-[:-108]NH2?[a])-NH1-(<[:90]H)(-[:30](<[:90]OH)-[:-30]*6(-M-(=[:-90]O)-NH-(=[:30]O)-=\phantom{L}))-?[b])-?[b](<[:90]H)--(<[:150]^{-}O_{3}SO)-)(<[:-150]H_3C)
}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

My questions:

1. How can I put the positive charge out the structure, like the example?
2. How can I draw the double bonds with one dashed line between N, NH1 and NH2?
3. How can I link the NH2 atom correctly with the hydrogen outside?
4. How can I put HN instead of M? I've been trying, but the bounds link in the H atom

Any help, indication, suggestion?

Comment: For the positive charge (1) I'd use an invisible bond: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267684/ For the atom groups and the bonds (3 & 4) I'd use the departure/arrival option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327278/

Comment: For the delocalized double bond (2) have a look in the `chemfig` manual section *Delocalized double bonds*

Comment: @clemens I'm not understandig how works the delocalized double bonds. I pasted the code from the manual and it is not working. The message isInvalid code (1000), should be in the range 0..15. \catcode‘\@
Missing $ inserted. \catcode‘\@
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode‘
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode‘
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. \catcode‘\@
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/decoration', to which you

Comment: @DanielValencia You need to change `‘` to `\`` (backtick)

Comment: @ DanielValencia errors without examples to reproduce them are often impossible to debug. I would have added an answer but @Troy already did, so…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Para copiar caracteres especiais como ç, á, à
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Para copiar caracteres especiais como ç, á, à
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} % You need this for q2

% From package documentation, pg 29, change ‘ to ` (2 instances)
\catcode`\@=11
\tikzset{
    ddbond/.style args={#1}{
        draw=none,
        decoration={%
            markings,
            mark=at position 0 with {
                \coordinate (CF@startdeloc) at (0,\dimexpr#1\CF@double@sep/2)
                coordinate (CF@startaxis) at (0,\dimexpr-#1\CF@double@sep/2);
            },
            mark=at position 1 with {
                \coordinate (CF@enddeloc) at (0,\dimexpr#1\CF@double@sep/2)
                coordinate (CF@endaxis) at (0,\dimexpr-#1\CF@double@sep/2);
                \draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.5pt] (CF@startdeloc)--(CF@enddeloc);
                \draw (CF@startaxis)--(CF@endaxis);
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\catcode`\@=12

\begin{document}
\chemfig{%
    *6(-(-[:-72]?[a])(<[:-150]H)
    -N*6(-[,,,,ddbond={+}](-[7,0.2,,,draw=none]{\scriptstyle+})
    (-[:-108,,,1,ddbond={-}]N?[a]H2)
    -[,,,,ddbond={+}]NH1-(<[:90]H)(-[:30](<[:90]OH)
    -[:-30]*6(-[,,,2]HN-(=[:-90]O)-NH-(=[:30]O)-
    =\phantom{L}))-?[b])-?[b](<[:90]H)--(<[:150]^{-}O_{3}SO)-)(<[:-150]H_3C)
}

\end{document}
```

Just some small notes on each question. The very well-written package documentation goes into more details, I'll just point you to what's relevant.

1. with `-[7,0.2,,,draw=none]{\scriptstyle+}`:
   This draws a `+` at the end of an invisible bond, drawn `-45deg` from the C atom (that's what the `7` means), `0.2*bond length` away.
2. with `-[,,,,ddbond={+/-}]`: this is taken from the [chemfig documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), pg 29. You need to use `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` in the preamble for this to work, and add the relevant part in the preamble. Then just add the `ddbond={+}` or `ddbond={-}` option to the relevant bonds (after 4 commas in the optional argument).
3. with `-[:-108,,,1]N?[a]H2`:
   This bond is drawn from the `+` to the NH2, so set its arrival atom to `1` explicitly, which is the N atom. (Try removing the `1` in the argument, note what you get).
4. with `-[,,,2]HN` instead of `-M`
   Similar with question 3, set the arrival atom to the second atom (the N), by passing `2` to the fourth optional argument.

[image: chemfig]

> **Off-topic:** Please refrain from asking multiple (unrelated) questions in a single TeX.SE question in the future. This not only increases your chances of the question(s) being answered, but it also allows other users with similar questions to find this question(s) (and solution(s)) more easily.

Comment: The LaTeX versions of ``\catcode`\@=11 `` and ``\catcode`\@=12 `` are `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: I have recently been trying to use delocalized bonds and have copied the code from pg 30 character for character but I am getting an error {! Undefined control sequence.<argument> 0,\dimexpr +\CF_doublesep/2'}. The error is basically saying it needs a number rather than a {+} or a {-} in the ddbond={+/-}. Can anyone else repeat this and get the same issue?